# Set the button to Enable while on Current Activity

Tags: java, android

I have 2 activity let say, "`activity_first.java`" and "`Activity_second.java`".
on `activity_first.java` i have 2 button which is `call activity second` and `Waiting`.
the `Activity_second.java` has a button also, i call it `Set Waiting to ENABLED`.
so, on running time, the `activity_first.java` will be call, the `call activity second` is set
to ENABLED and the `Waiting` is set to DISABLED. when you clicked the `call activity second`, the `Activity_second.java` will be show, but the `activity_first.java` will not be closed, just stay on running so i can go back on back keypad of my phone, so at the `Activity_second.java` if i clicked the `Set Waiting to ENABLED` button, the `Waiting` button from `activity_first.java` will be set to ENABLED, so if i close the `Activity_second.java` the `Waiting` button is already ENABLED by clicking the `Set Waiting to ENABLED` button. my problem is, i dont know how to set the `Waiting` button to enabled while on `Activity_second.java`.

```
any body can help? 
thank you so much!
```

Comment: you mey set `mybutton.setVisible(GONE);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, don't write long paragraph, break down your question and state it in simple points :)

You can easily maintain the state of `waiting` button by maintaining `static boolean variable`
and implementing the `onRestart` method in `first activity`.

Here is the link to a source code. Download and just examine the code. hope you will find this helpful

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-ZuLKRNNO7BVUZpQVpOYVQ3X0k/view?usp=sharing

Feel free to ask anything.

Here is the code.

ActivityFirst.java

```
public class ActivityFirst extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

Button btnCallActivitySecond;
Button btnWaiting;

//variable that maintains the state of button
public static boolean status = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);


    btnCallActivitySecond = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnActCall);
    btnWaiting = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnWainting);       

    btnWaiting.setEnabled(status);

    btnCallActivitySecond.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnWaiting.setOnClickListener(this);
}
/*This method will be called each time
  whenever you press back button from second activity*/
@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestart();
    btnWaiting.setEnabled(status);
    Toast.makeText(this, "restart "+ status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (arg0.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnActCall:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivitySecond.class);
        i.putExtra("status", status);
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    case R.id.btnWainting:
        Toast.makeText(this, " "+ status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    }


}  ... }
```

ActivitySecond.java

```
public class ActivitySecond extends ActionBarActivity {

Button btnWaitEnable;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    btnWaitEnable = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnWaitEnable);

    btnWaitEnable.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //This statement will return the opposite of what 
            //is stored in that public static boolean variable
            ActivityFirst.status = (ActivityFirst.status == true)?false:true;

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: why don't you post the code here,rather than on a file storage.. basically, SO is an instant solution website and you redirecting someone is really not a go-to solution to me.. that's just btw.

Comment: great.. +1 for that, quick suggestion, put your boolean in a singleton class.,.